# How to get enum's value within JPQL-query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, enums, spring-el

I have the follow entity with enum as field:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Example implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private Type type;
}
```

The enum:

```java
public enum Type implements Serializable {
    EASY,
    NORMAL,
    HARD
}
```

At last I have the follow DTO:

```java
public record ExampleDto(Integer id, String value) {
}
```

It is important that `ExampleDto#value` has `String` type not `Type` type. I want to use the DTO as projection in `Spring Data JPA` but I have a problem. I do not understand how I can convert enum value to string within JPQL-query. I tried to do something like that:

```java
@Query("""
       SELECT new com.example.project.ExampleDto(e.id, e.type.name)
       FROM   Example e 
       WHERE  e.id = :id""")
ExampleDto findById(Integer id);
```

But it does not work. So how I can convert enum to string within JPQL? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The JPA will automatically convert the enum value to its name as a string when constructing the ExampleDto. You don't need to explicitly call name() on the enum.

```
@Query("""
       SELECT new com.example.project.ExampleDto(e.id, e.type)
       FROM   Example e 
       WHERE  e.id = :id""")
ExampleDto findById(Integer id);
```